# MySQL Integration Test "Query not found"

Tags: mysql, testcontainers

When running a testcontainers MySQL,

```
@ClassRule
public static final MySQLContainer mysql = (MySQLContainer) new MySQLContainer("mysql:5.6").withInitScript("init/test.sql")
```

I get the error "Query not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking my SQL syntax over and over, I had a blank new line at the end of the .sql file. Removing this (so the carat is at the end of my INSERT INTO ....;) resolves the issue.